# mouse touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, ubuntu-netbook

i just installed Ubuntu in my newly bought acer aspire one 725 netbook, along with windows 7 as another OS. whenever i try to work on Ubuntu, my mouse touch pad doesn't work, it works nicely in windows 7, but not in Ubuntu, i've evb tried Fn+F7 key combinition, but it wont help. what could be the problem and solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System setting>>mouse and touchpad, see if you can see touchpad settings there, it must be in a seperated tab